# How to delete old child records when updating the Parent Entity

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I am currently working on a Bi-directional OneToMany Hibernate association using annotations. 
I am stuck up with a problem.

A Parent entity has many child entities. Whenever I update the Child set in Parent and try to update the Parent entity, still the old Child entries exists in the Child table. so Parent contains duplicate child records.

Whenever I update Parent entity, automatically its Child entries should also be updated correctly with no duplicates, meaning already existing child entities should be deleted.

I googled and found that there is a dirty way of achieving this. Getting the existing Child entities of a Parent and iterating through each child and deleting each child entity using session.delete(child).  This is very bad approach, I know.

Can we achieve the above thing in a better way using annotations? Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [delete-orphan](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade) cascade setting. When a child is removed from the parent, the child will be deleted.

You will have to modify the collection that was loaded and exists in the session for delete-orphan to work. Which means the collection has to be a PersistentSet or whatever and you remove and add objects to it.

Something like

```
Set<Product> newProducts = new HashSet<Products>();
newProducts.add(prod1);
newProducts.add(prod2);
order.setProducts(newProducts);
```

will only set the parent_id int he products table to null, it won't delete them. Now something like

```
Set<Product> products = order.getProducts();
products.clear();
products.add(prod1);
products.add(prod2);
```

should delete the children.

And remember for any delete-orphan to work the orders and products must be loaded and exist in the session.

Comment: Thanks Pond for the reply. What i am exactly looking for is, whenever Parent's childs set is updated and upon saving the parent, automatically old child's should be removed. Anyway that we can achieve this?, instead of iterating through each and every old child and explicitly removing them.

Comment: Thanks Robby - I would bet this is the issue I'm seeing. Wow - Hibernate has gone down even further in my estimation - and it wasn't too highly regarded in the first place! What a piece of S#%*!